# How to avoid spelling a complex type in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is coming up while using SwiftUI bit it really is a fundamental Swift question about types.  Trying to have a view like so:

```
struct BorderedRectangle1: View {
  let gesture: Gesture

  init(color: Color, border: Bool) {
    self.gesture = TapGesture().modifiers(.option).onEnded {
      // do something
    }.simultaneously(with: TapGesture().modifiers(.command).onEnded {
      // do something else
    })
  }

  var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
      .gesture(gesture)
  }
}
```

but this doesn't compile with *Use of protocol 'Gesture' as a type must be written 'any Gesture'. Replace 'Gesture' with 'any Gesture'*

Replacing `let gesture: Gesture` => `let gesture: any Gesture` eliminates the above error but another error appears on `Rectangle()` in the body: *Type 'any Gesture' cannot conform to 'Gesture'*.

I was able to "fix" it by making the gesture property computed:

```
  var gesture: some Gesture {
    TapGesture().modifiers(.option).onEnded {
      // do something
    }.simultaneously(with: TapGesture().modifiers(.command).onEnded {
      // do something else
    })  }
```

I get it that the compiler must be able to infer a type in both the declaration and use sites.  So how to make it work while keeping the declaration of gesture as a stored property and without spelling the explicit type which is `SimultaneousGesture<_EndedGesture<_ModifiersGesture<TapGesture>>, _EndedGesture<_ModifiersGesture<TapGesture>>>`

```
let gesture: ?? // <= what goes in here?
```

Comment: IMO having UI elements (including gestures) initialize in `init` is awkward, and doesn't really give you anything. Use `init` to initialize _data only_, and just stick to using UI elements where they are needed. And if you want to isolate them, use calculated variables, or if they are reusable define your custom ViewModifier

Comment: This code doesn't show any need for the `any gesture`. I think its better to pass the `handlers` instead of the gesture. So there will be nothing to force cast or complex type at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a generic type, which will be the type of the stored property. That generic type must conform to `Gesture`.

Here's a code that compiles:

```
// Create a generic type that conforms to Gesture
struct BorderedRectangle1<G: Gesture>: View {
    
    // The property is of type G
    let gesture: G
    
    init(color: Color, border: Bool) {
        self.gesture = TapGesture().modifiers(.option).onEnded {
            // do something
        }.simultaneously(with: TapGesture().modifiers(.command).onEnded {
            // do something else
        }) as! G        // Ensure the gesture is of type G
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .gesture(gesture)
    }
}
```

If you need to pass a gesture to the `View`, here's how it works:

```
// Create a generic type that conforms to Gesture
struct BorderedRectangle1<G: Gesture>: View {
    
    // The property is of type G
    let gesture: G
    
    // The parameter is of type G
    init(gesture: G) {
        self.gesture = gesture
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .gesture(gesture)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach (coming from mostly C++ I didn't realize type deduction like so is possible).  Indeed, this code for the view compiles.  But instantiating it seems to be a problem: *Generic parameter 'G' could not be inferred*.  So it seems we do need an argument of type `G` for the inference to work?  Is there a way to make this work without injecting the gesture as an argument to init?

Comment: @giik In the code in the answer `G` is inferred through the parameter. You have to pass it something with a known concrete type e.g. `BorderedRectangle(gesture: TapGesture())`.

Comment: Yes @JeremyP and sorry I wasn't clear.  I had the impression that it can be done without passing it as an argument (top listing in HunterLion's reply), passing it will definitely work and the type will be inferred.

Comment: @giik Then you need to explicitly spell it as a type parameter in the initialiser `BorderedRectangle<TapGesture>(color: ...)`